# Declare an array using /bin/sh in a single line

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, syntax

This array declaration works in `bash` but NOT in `/bin/sh`!

```
array=("1" "3" "5")
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find a way to define an array in a single line in `/bin/sh`. I thought there must be a way as the commands do accepts a list of argument. Is there a way?

Comment: sh doesn't support arrays. if you link sh to a shell supporting arrays -like bash, zsh, etc-, it'll work though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: Ok, you're right. I associated this question to that one. That one, though, is a very broad one covering lots of difference...

Comment: Also, your declaration doesn't work in Bash either because of blanks around `=`.

Comment: You're right. I fixed it.